# Comparison not working when Include is added

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got the following user class in my database that has two relations where Profile can be null.

```
public class User
{
  //...

  public string Sign {get; set;}

  public long? ProfileId {get; set;}
  public virtual Profile Profile {get; set;}

  public long PersonId {get; set;}
  public virtual Person Person { get; set;}

}
```

I'm trying to search for a user with X sign attribute. So I'm doing this:

```
var users = Context.Users.Where(u => String.Compare(u.Sign, X) == 0).ToList();
```

Till this point works. But I need to include Profile and Person in this search and when I use `Include()` method it crashes (users do not include who has Profile null) for users that have Profile null.

```
var users = Context.Users.Include("Profile").Include("Person").Where(u => String.Compare(u.Sign, X) == 0).ToList(); //stopedworking (users do not include who has Profile null)
```

How could I make this work?

**Updated**
Add virtual and Id references, forgot to put it.

Comment: On the face of it, everything seems fine with the syntax. Looking at the `User` class, does making `Profile` and `Person` `virtual` do anything?

Comment: What means "it crashes" and "stopped working" at all? Guys, please, can you provide the error including stack trace and everything else when you want us to fix your error?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I forgot to put it here, but yes it has it. TimSchmelter there's no stack trace, just result of the query changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include system.data.entity, which enables you to use [`Queryable.Include<T, TProperty>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) instead of  [Include(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
string X = ...
var result = dbContext.Users
    .Include(user => user.Profile)
    .Where(user => user.Sign == X);
```

By the way, your query selects the complete user and the complete profile, which is a waste of processing power if you only plan to use a few properties. In that case I'd recommend using select:

```
var result = dbContext.Users
    .Where(user => user.Sign == X)
    .Select(user => new
    {   // select only the properties you'll use after the query
        ...

        // from the Profile, select only the properties you'll use after the query
        Profiles = user.Profile.Select(profile => new
        {
             ...
        }
    });
```